# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject returning all vaules null

Tags: c#, json

My brain burning problem: The deserialize code from newtonsoft.json only returns null on all strings:
[image]

Also i checked if the variables are exactly named as the one in the json, they are. This here is my Deserialize Code:

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filepath);
string jsonString = r.ReadToEnd();
GlobalVariables.ItemSer m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GlobalVariables.ItemSer>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine(GlobalVariables.ItemSer.ARSID); //breakpointed here
GlobalVariables.ApplicationState.loadjson = true;
```

These are the Variables from the GlobalVariable class:

```
[Serializable]
public class ItemSer
{
    public static string EssentialID { get; set; }
    public static string MotherID { get; set; }
    public static string SimpleID { get; set; }
    public static string PassiveID { get; set; }
    public static string ARSID { get; set; }
}
```

And the json that is getting deserialized:

```
{
"config":
[
    {
    "EssentialID": "5500",
    "MotherID": "6600",
    "SimpleID": "55",
    "PassiveID": "870155",
    "ARSID": "00551100"
    },
    {
    "EssentialID": "6600",
    "MotherID": "5500",
    "SimpleID": "66",
    "PassiveID": "870166",
    "ARSID": "00661100"
    }
]
```

}

i really don't know why the vaules are returning null, so i choosed to write a question instead wasting more time into googling.

Comment: You have a collection in config, but you are doing one-on-one mapping. Try creating a list of `ItemSer` and map deserialization to that list.

Comment: well the JSON in question doesn't match the shape of the class you want to deserialize it into. The JSON has one property named `config` which appears to contain an array of objects that match the definition of `ItemSer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSON, there is a property `config` that holds a list of objects. When deserializing, the code tries to match this JSON structure to the ItemSer class. The JSON must match the class structure very closely and does not pick the first matching part of the JSON.

So you need to adjust the class structure to the JSON so that the deserializer can connect the two:

```
public class Container
{
  [JsonProperty("config")]
  public IList<ItemSer> Config { get; set; }
}

// ...

var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(jsonString);
var itemSer = container.Config.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is an object with single array property `config`. You need another structure to deserialize it right:

```
public class ItemsModel 
{
  public List<ItemSer> config {get;set;}
}
```

then

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemsModel>(jsonString);
var m = model.config.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just parse your json, and deserialize only a list

```
List<GlobalVariables.ItemSer> config = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["config"]
                                .ToObject<List<GlobalVariables.ItemSer>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss the type of the `json`. Your deserializer looks for there is an object. But there is an array. Please try wrap your model with `List<>`

The example of model classes:

```cs
    public class Item
    {
        public string EssentialID { get; set; }
        public string MotherID { get; set; }
        public string SimpleID { get; set; }
        public string PassiveID { get; set; }
        public string ARSID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Config
    {
        public List<Item> ItemList{ get; set; }
    }
```

And access:

```cs
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filepath);
string jsonString = r.ReadToEnd();
Config m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine(Config.Items.FirstOrDefault().ARSID);
GlobalVariables.ApplicationState.loadjson = true;
```

Comment: Still won't work because the JSON isn't an array. It's an object with one property that that holds an array.

Comment: I miss that answer is updated. @MichaelWelch

Comment: see the answer by @pakeha_by, I think your `Config` class needs a property named `config` (or `Config`), not `ItemList` which is not a property in the JSON.